# How to tell if suffix *er* means a person, a tool or an action?

Tags: meaning, verbs, nouns, verb-forms

Many verbs can be suffixed by *er*, which makes them nouns. However, some nouns made this way refer to persons, while others refer to tools or actions. For example:

- *pay*: *payer* (the person who pays)
- *cook*: *cooker* (the tool used for cooking)
- *pray*: *prayer* (the action of praying)

I haven't seen people calling a payment tool (such as [Square Reader](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00HZYK3CO)) *payer*. Similarly, I haven't seen people calling someone who cooks *cooker*. But people do call someone who teaches *teacher*.

So how can language learners tell, for an unknown verb, which concept it means when suffixed by *er*? Furthermore, by the [pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle), you can't precisely fit three concepts into one form. Are there any rules or heuristics governing *er* suffix?

Comment: The pigeonhole principle is a mathematical concept. In a natural language it is common for one word to have multiple meanings and nuances.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to learn the words, one by one.

Not every verb has a noun in the form -er. For example "meaner" (from the verb "mean") Others have a specific or limited meaning, for example "seer" (from the verb see) means a fortune teller.

Often context will make it clear what meaning is intended. "Put the pan on the cooker" probably doesn't refer to a person; "The writer of the book" probably is a person.

There are a great many "-er" nouns that are not related to any verb: "answer", "ladder", "brother"

So there is no general rule. Most -er nouns are [agent nouns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agent_noun), they mean the person or thing that does something. The particular meaning needs to be learned word-by-word.

(Words ending in -er are a cause of difficulty in some word games (such as Countdown) as they are not permitted unless specifically mentioned in the dictionary)

Comment: And a ladder is not a tool for ladding ...

Comment: I'll add something to that effect, Also "answer", "brother" and lots more examples.

Comment: Oh, bother. Now I'm in a dither. ;)

Comment: Get out quickly before it dithes you!  (No, that is not a word in common use I made it up just now for a joke.)

Comment: Technically, *answer* is related to *swear* and *ladder* distantly related to *lean*.

Comment: Related to, but not formed as "swear"+ "-er" as an agent noun. Similarly Ladder is not an agent noun from lean, any ancestor word.